# Criteria builder function using jsonb_path_exists

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to filter data with criteria builder. Simple date filtering works as below. The problem appears in the column containing the json array as below.
I want to remain records having pair {"key": "market", "value": "australia"}.
Sql query filters correctly: records 1 and 3 remain. How to implement this query in Java?

| id | attributes | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"key": "market", "value": "australia"}, {"key": "language", "value": "polish"}] | 2022-05-24 17:30:04.046000 |
| 2 | [{"key": "country", "value": "australia"}, {"key": "language", "value": "polish"}] | 2022-05-24 17:30:04.046000 |
| 3 | [{"key": "market", "value": "australia"}, {"key": "language", "value": "polish"}] | 2022-05-24 17:30:04.046000 |
| 4 | [{"key": "market", "value": "brazil"}, {"key": "language", "value": "polish"}] | 2022-05-24 17:30:04.046000 |
| 5 | [{"key": "market", "value": "brazil"}, {"key": "language", "value": "australia"}] | 2022-05-24 17:30:04.046000 |

`SELECT * FROM run WHERE jsonb_path_exists("attributes", '$[*] ? ((@.key == "market") && (@.value == "australia"))')`

```
public static Specification<Run> andGreaterThanFromDate(Specification<Run> specification, LocalDateTime fromDate) {
    return specification.and((Root<Run> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> cb
        .greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(LAUNCH_START_DATE), fromDate));
}
```

```
public static Specification<Run> andAttributeContains(Specification<Run> specification, String attribute) {
    return specification.and((Root<Run> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> cb
        .function(
            ???
}
```

I found only the use of simple sql functions whose arguments are fields of the record. I can't use this function because the argument is json array.
Thank you in advance for your help.

I've tried sth like that:

```
public static Specification<Run> andDynamicAttributeContains(Specification<Run> specification) {
    return specification.and((Root<Run> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> cb.isTrue(
        cb.function(
            "jsonb_path_exists",
            Boolean.class,
            cb.parameter(Path.class, "launch_attributes"),
            cb.parameter(Boolean.class, "$[*] ? ((@.key == \"market\") && (@.value == \"australia\"))"))));
  }
```

but I got error `org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@'`

Comment: For now, I gave up, while saving I extract the attribute to the column and filter it.

Answer (score 0):

I have described how to filter using  the `jsonb_path_exists` function in the following answer. For details check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73280813/8752286

TLDR: I called the function like this:

```
        return criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_filter",
            String.class,
            entityRoot.get("json"),
            jsonPathExpression
    ).in(Boolean.TRUE);
```

However I had to create a wrapper function `jsonb_filter` for `jsonb_path_exists` which accepts a `varchar` parameter instead of a `jsonpath`