# Usage of PostgreSQL function "jsonb_path_exists" in jpa criteria api

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

I would like to call the postgresql function `jsonb_path_exists` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) using JPA criteria api.

Lets assume i have the following query:

```
select id from person where jsonb_path_exists(person.json,'$.some_property[0].typ ? (@ =="Something")');
```

Via the CriteriaBuilder i would do something like:

```
        var jsonQuery = jsonPath + " ? (@ ==\"" + value + "\")"; // evaluates to '$.some_property[0].typ ? (@ =="Something")'
        criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_path_exists",
                        String.class,
                        entityRoot.get("json"),
                        criteriaBuilder.literal(jsonQuery)
                )
                .in(Boolean.TRUE);
```

However i have not figured out how to cast the jsonQuery which is provided as string to postgres `jsonpath` type. Hence i receive the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_path_exists(jsonb, character varying) does not exist
```

The correct signature is
`jsonb_path_exists(target jsonb, path jsonpath [, vars jsonb [, silent bool]])`

This issue exists for all functions with a `jsonpath` parameter e.g. `jsonb_path_query`,`jsonb_path_match`,`jsonb_path_query_first`

Does anybody have a clue on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this issue by writing a PostgreSQL wrapper function which I now call instead of `jsonb_path_exists`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_filter(target jsonb, path varchar)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT cost 1 AS
$func$
  BEGIN
      RETURN jsonb_path_exists(target,CAST(path AS jsonpath));
  END
$func$;
```

Calling the created `jsonb_filter` function does the job:

```
        return criteriaBuilder.function("jsonb_filter",
                String.class,
                entityRoot.get("json"),
                jsonPathExpression
        ).in(Boolean.TRUE);
```

Make sure not to include surrounding single quotes in the `jsonPathExpression`, e.g. use `$.your_expression` instead of `'$.your_expression'`.

Comment: +1 The reason is that any JPA container just passes this down to the server via JDBC. And there is no PostgreSQL native JSON type (like it exists in some other Databases, but ofc highly proprietary). The PostgreSQL JDBC driver also does not understand the javax.json.JsonPointer data type. Thus it will always be passed down as java.lang.String. It might be considered as bug in PostgreSQL from a user POV, but it is ok-ish behaviour from a pure Java/DB/JPA perspective.